# Magento - getShippingPreFee($cost) to show on available.phtml

Tags: php

I am adding fee's to my shipping cost on `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract` in local.

I am adding them at the `public function _getPerpackagePrice`
I am having it return the `$cost` + fees basically. Once this is done the shipping then includes the Fee's.

```
protected function _getPerpackagePrice($cost, $handlingType, $handlingFee)
{
    if ($handlingType == self::HANDLING_TYPE_PERCENT) {
        return ($cost + ($cost * $handlingFee/100)) * $this->_numBoxes;
    }

    //MY CODE CALCULATIONS HERE
    if ($path_current !==$cartPaths){
       return ($cost_c  +$sub_c+$handling_c+$tax_c + $cost + $fee + $mattress_cost_c);
    }   
}
```

But on `checkout/onepage/shippping_method/availabile.phtml` I want to just simply `echo` the variable `$cost` from `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract` since its the shipping prior to the fee.

```
public function getShippingPreFee($cost){return ($cost);}
```

If someone know how to get `$cost` from the abstract `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract` and `echo` it on `checkout/onepage/shippping_method/availabile.phtml` thats is what I am looking to do. I already know about putting the `Return` prior to the `$fees` on `total/abstract.php` and thats not my goal.

Comment: This is not good answer but you can try magento session
**Set Cost **
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCustomCost($cost);
**Get Cost**
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCustomCost();

Answer (score 0):

Please set custom price with below function which is in carrier model

```
protected function _getStandardRate()

        {



            $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);

            $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $rate->setMethod('large');

            $rate->setMethodTitle(Mage::helper('YOUR HELPER')->__('YOUR METHOD'));

            $rate->setPrice(300);//Custom Price

            $rate->setCost(0);

            return $rate;

        }
```

Comment: Is this a alternate way to add the fee?
Also for $rate->setPrice(300) I can add the variable $cost + $fees correct?

Also on the frontend for availaible.phtml where it would normally get getShippingAmount(); for each carrier option, will that return the calculations without or with the new customer fee?

Currently right now im getting shipping+fees with that code, so i was hoping to find a way on the front end to access the function  getShippingPreFee which would return the $cost, 1 step prior to me adding fee's in the abstract.

Comment: Yes Just calculate cost as per your own choice with any value then set it as final shipping cost under setPrice() . Please look at the link so it will be more clear. http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/